# I have a problem using the Ternary Operator in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, react-props, conditional-operator

I have a page that is supposed to generate sections automatically. Everything transfers fine except the ternary operator.

**The data I using:**

```
carList = [
    {
        id: 0,
        brand: "Lorem",
        model: "Lorem",
        dealer: "Lorem",
        main_image: "Lorem",
        sections: [
            {
                id: 0,
                section_type: "",
                section_title: "Lorem",
                section_text: "Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem",
                image_left: "Lorem1.png",
                image_center: null,
                image_right: null
            }
       ]
  }
```

**IMPORTANT: The data is entered manually, it is not imported from JSON**

The problem arises when I want to check the ternary operator if "image_left" or "right" is null.

**This is how they are sent:**

```
const { car_id } = this.state;

    const sections = this.carList[car_id].sections.map((section, index) => (
        <CarContent data={this.carList} car_id={this.state.car_id} section_id={this.carList[car_id].sections[index].id} />
    ))
```

**And this is how they are received:**

```
const CarContent = (props) => {
const { car_id, data, section_id } = props;
const section = data[car_id].sections[section_id];

return (
    <div className={section.section_type}>
        <div className="section_images">
            {section.image_left !== null ? <div className="image_left"> // Here < ------
                <img src={section.image_left} alt="" />
            </div> : ""}
            {(section.image_right !== null) ? <div className="image_right"> // And here < ------
                <img src={section.image_right} alt="" />
            </div> : ""}
        </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**The same situation happens when I want to check if eg "section_text" is empty. I just wish that a given component would not show up when it is empty or null**

Comment: What is the issue? What is the problem? I see no overt issues in your code. Seems the parent component has all the data it needs to pass ***just*** `section` to the `Car` component. Why pass all the props every time?

Comment: Please, paste the error message into question.

Comment: You also have a typo in 2nd condition, you are checking `image_left` when there should be `image_right`

Comment: The problem is that the section still shows up: https://imgur.com/a/zxeZIU5

Comment: Yes it does, cause you condition is wrong. `(section.image_left !== null) ?` instead it should be `section.image_right !== null ?`

Comment: @Ulou you are rigth but i fixed this and still sections left/right show up

Comment: You've still not said what the problem is. Can you try making a *running* codesandbox that actually reproduces your issue for us to inspect and live debug in? The ternary is fine... if it's still rendering anyting it's because there's something to render. See [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible Code Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you are getting the `section` is not correct . This example works here because both your index and section happens to be `0` . But this will be an issue if your `sectionId` is `10` and the index in which it resides is `5`. With your current code you will fetch the section in the index `10` .

```
const section = data[car_id].sections.find(section => section.id === section_id);
```

I think what you are looking for is conditional rendering .

```
{
  section.image_left && (
    <div className="image_left">
      <img src={section.image_left} alt="" />
    </div>
  );
}
```

This renders the div only when there is a value in the `section.image_left` .

Comment: This changes nothing (besides syntax) in compere to OP code.

Comment: @ulou In fairness, it *does* render `null` instead of `""` for the sad-path.

Comment: I just added this answer based on what the author mentioned - `I just wish that a given component would not show up when it is empty or null` . lets wait for him to confirm :-)

Comment: @Shyam Your code is working, thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: updated my answer to retrieve the section correctly, because the way you are getting the section is not correct and it might lead to problems.

Answer (score 1):

Pay attention to he operator && here.

```
{section.image_right && 
   (<div className="image_right">
     <img src={section.image_right} alt="Give a descriptive alt here"/>
   </div>)
}
```

This checks if image_right is not empty or null.

- If it is not, then it will render that div with the img inside.
- If it empty or null, then it will not render the div and img.

Comment: Yeah it will render `null` instead. Additionally there is already identical answer.